# How to install and run tesseract OCR using PHP

Tags: php, ocr, tesseract

I am a newbie when it comes to tesseract. I want to implement a text search from images based on user input. I heard about tesseract and I think it's a good open source solution for implementing the search. My idea is to scan the images, get out the text and its coordinates from the image and highlight the portion of the text which the user input.

I have downloaded the source code from  http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/list, but I couldn't find a `tesseract` executable in any source code for using it on the command line. If someone could guide me how to proceed so that I can accomplish my task, that would be of great help. I have seen in another link that we can use the `exec` command. But when I downloaded the source code and tried to run it, it always produces:

> Tesseract is not recognized as an internal or external ...

Comment: Thanks.. but can't I get the exe or binary from google and use the command line?

Comment: If somebody else compiled it for your system and offers the download, then yes. Otherwise, as written, get ready to compile your own. Rocks!

Comment: OK... Any better way to get text search from image?